# Implementing a function with keeping accumulator on OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, accumulate

I wrote a function that given length of a string in a list. For example, when user enter `stringy ["a";"bbb";"cc";"ddddd"]`. It returns `[("a",1); ("bbb",3); ("cc",2); ("ddddd",5)]`. I want to do same function with accumulator. How can I do that ?

```
let rec stringy lst =
    match lst with 
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs ->  (x, String.length x) ::stringy xs ;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence is to add another parameter to the function that collects up the answer as you process the input list.

Here's a function that multiplies every element of a list by 2:

```
let rec double list =
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> (h * 2) :: double t
```

Here is the same function with an accumulator:

```
let rec double_acc accum list =
    match list with
    | [] -> accum
    | h :: t -> double_acc ((2 * h) :: accum) t
```

This second version has two problems: (1) it takes an extra parameter that's not interesting to a caller; (2) it returns the list in reverse order. You can fix these problems by writing a wrapper function that adds the extra parameter and then reverses the result with `List.rev`.

**Update**

A wrapper function is just a function that calls another function, possibly adjusting the parameters and the return value.

Here's a wrapper function that calculates *sin^2* by wrapping *cos*:

```
 let wrap_sin2 theta =
     let cos_theta = cos theta in
     1.0 -. cos_theta *. cos_theta
```

For `double_acc` above, the internal call needs an extra `[]` parameter, and the result needs to be reversed using `List.rev`. I leave it to you to figure out how to handle your actual problem, as I suspect this is a homework exercise.

Comment: how can I do that with wrapper ?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have more questions, you should provide some code you wrote.

Comment: nitpick: your `wrap_sin` function computes `|sin . |`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll switch to sin^2 x.

Answer (score 0):

If i use the accumulator constraint :

```
    let stringy lst = 
       lst
       |> List.fold_left (fun a s -> ((String.sub s 0 1),(String.length s) ) :: a ) []
       |> List.rev
```

But why do you want to use an accumulator ?

Here another way :

```
    let stringy lst = 
       lst
       |> List.map (fun s -> ((String.sub s 0 1),(String.length s) ) )
```

Comment: Using an accumulators makes the function tail recursive which can help avoid stack overflows when the input list is big.

Comment: If you handle the recursion manually yes, you need an accumulator, but if you use standard list library tail recursion is already provided in many functions in the case of the example rev_map is tail recursive without needing you to handle the accumulator.